# can't copy address field data with special chars, to anther address field in salesforce using javascript button quote object

Tags: javascript, java, salesforce

while Coping the billing address to shipping address in quote object using the javascript button,  the billing address which has the special characters as (.,@), throws javascript error.

please advice

Comment: Please share your code and the JS error

Comment: Please give us some context, preferably some code

Comment: {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
var quotObj = new sforce.SObject("Quote"); 
quotObj.ID = '{!Quote.Id}'; 
quotObj.ShippingStreet = '{!Quote.BillingStreet}'; 
quotObj.ShippingCity = '{!Quote.BillingCity}'; 
quotObj.ShippingState = '{!Quote.BillingState}'; 
quotObj.ShippingPostalCode = '{!Quote.BillingPostalCode}'; 
quotObj.ShippingCountry = '{!Quote.BillingCountry}'; 
var result=sforce.connection.update([quotObj]); 
location.reload(true);

Comment: The error was A problem with the Onclick Javascript button or link was encountered. Invalid or unexpected token.

Comment: This is a problem  I am facing on the code.